# Change input box type base on json using ng-repeat in Angular JS

Tags: json, angularjs, forms

I want to create a data driven form using angular JS.

I am able to do ng-repeat and loop through the JSON fields for each title and include an input box with in.

But now I need to have different text box type for different field (also pass in from JSON. such as 'input' or 'textarea'

```
<div>
    <div ng-repeat="x in form">
        <h4>{{x.field_name}}</h4>
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="{{x.field_name}}" ng-model="result[x.field_name]">
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to be able to change the  tag based on the JSON I passed in.

I've tried using

```
<x.field_ui_type
```

I've also tried

```
<{{x.field_ui_type}}
```

but none of them seems to work

Comment: Use type="{{x.field_ui_type}}"

Comment: Do you want different input box type or different field like input, select,textarea ?

Comment: You have to use ng-switch on field name and based on field name select appropriate field control. You cannot dynamically create fields like input and textarea unless manuplulate dom using jquery or javascript to dynamically populate it on load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="x in form">
    <h4>{{x.field_name}}</h4>
    <div ng-switch on="x.field_ui_type">
        <textarea ng-switch-when="textarea" ng-model="result[x.field_name]"></textarea>
        <input type="textbox" ng-switch-when="input" ng-model="result[x.field_name]" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: how do i do it for ng-repeat?